# Detecting missing and extra numbers in integer sequence

Tags: matlab, vector, compare, sequence, matching

I am looking for a way to detect mistakes in a series of responses, logged as integers. The correct series (i.e. no mistakes) consists of a repeating pattern of 8 digits, recurring 28 times. I am interested to find instances of missing digits (so incomplete target sequences) as well as extra digits (so digits added into target sequences).

Up to now, I have just looked at the number of times a correct 8-digit sequence occurred by running through the whole series and using an if-statement to detect the occurrence of the whole sequence, which helps to detect (& potentially discard) parts of the series with no errors. It's likely not the best/fastest/prettiest way to do it but I think it works (Edit: strfind is clearly a more elegant option). Comparing vectors directly seems hard as they may have different sizes (although of course I'm curious if there's a solution for that, too).

So, let's say the target sequence is [24341123], and the full series is a vector of digits, all between 1 and 4, named resp (with a length of about 210-230 digits all, 8*28=224 if they're perfect).

```
correctsequences=0
for t=1:(numel(resp-8))
if resp(t)==2 && resp(t+1)==4 && resp(t+2)==3 && resp(t+3)==4 && resp(t+4)==1 && resp(t+5)==1 && resp(t+6)==2 && resp(t+7)==3; 
correctsequences=correctsequences+1
end end
```

So this will be enough only if there are no mistakes in the sequences, but if there are extra digits in between the targets they will already be missed.

I have been looking around for a way to find missing and extra digits within the target sequence repeated in the series, some queries have led me to regex methods (which I have no knowledge of at all), or only matching sequences rather than finding deviations, as I'm doing above.

What I need, ideally, is something that gives me a count of each type of mistake (missing and extra), but I'd already be happy to have some combination score of the two. I only have very basic matlab literacy (as you may have guessed from the example above) and would be grateful for any pointers that would prevent me from my worst case scenario, namely just checking the length, discarding all the sequences in the series that contain no errors, and eyeballing the remaining sequences to identify added and missing digits within each target.. I'm hoping this is actually a basic question for which I only need to locate the right function!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use `strfind`:

```
target = [2 4 3 4 1 1 2 3];
% generate sequences
resp1 = repmat(target,[1 28]);
resp2 = [randi(4,[1 20]) resp1 randi(4,[1 10])];
resp3 = [repmat(target,[1 27]) randi(4,[1 8])];
% find all sequences of target
k1 = strfind(resp1,target);
k2 = strfind(resp2,target);
k3 = strfind(resp3,target);
% find 28 sequences?
found1 = isequal(diff(k1),8*ones(1,27)); % true
found2 = isequal(diff(k2),8*ones(1,27)); % true
found3 = isequal(diff(k3),8*ones(1,27)); % false
% find extras
kk1 = bsxfun(@plus,k1,(0:7)');
kk1 = kk1(:)';
extraIdxs1 = 1:numel(resp1);
extraIdxs1(kk1) = [];
kk2 = bsxfun(@plus,k2,(0:7)');
kk2 = kk2(:)';
extraIdxs2 = 1:numel(resp2);
extraIdxs2(kk2) = [];
kk3 = bsxfun(@plus,k3,(0:7)');
kk3 = kk3(:)';
extraIdxs3 = 1:numel(resp3);
extraIdxs3(kk3) = [];
```

Comment: Thanks! Clearly strfind is a better way to detect intact sequences. :)
From what I can tell, the rest of the code (from 'find extras') locates all the remaining elements, with extraIdxs as the index, correct?

What I am looking for is a way to count the mistakes in the resp series, so if there is a missing or extra digit within a target sequence, this will get flagged somehow. Unless I am missing something in this code, the 'extras' would now still need to be inspected by eye to find the errors, is that right?

Comment: you can do `length(extraIdxs)` to detect the number of extra digits. about the missing ones - it's not well defined what do you mean, can you give an example of a `target` and a `resp` with a *missing digit*?

Comment: Ah, apologies for the unclarity. An extra digit would be if somewhere in the series, for instance this occurs: ... 2 4 3 3 4 1 1 2 3 ... -> a target sequence in which one extra digit is added, thus counting one extra. Similarly, a missing digit would be where something like this occurs: ...2 4 3 1 1 2 3 ... -> a target sequence with one digit missing.

Comment: Rather than classifying the remaining digits in an otherwise correct sequence as mistakes, I'm trying to find a way to detect the number of deviations from the target sequence. I can try strfind for increasing lengths of partially correct targets (starting at the beginning or the end, or maybe making use of wildcards?), or look for instances where specific number pairs occur in succession, or something like that... But that is where my ideas ended!